# Samba Annon Access

Tags: server, windows, samba

I trying to configure my samba so anyone can access it without any form of password or password prompt.

Everyone needs to get full read/write access straight in. It is essential to work from a windows box.

Below is my smb.conf file.

Any ideas or something i have missed?

```
[global]
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        map to guest = smbguest
        obey pam restrictions = No
        pam password change = No
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n
*Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n
*password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        unix password sync = Yes
        syslog = 0
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 1000
        socket options = TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=8192
SO_SNDBUF=8192 dns proxy = No
        wins support = Yes
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        idmap config * : backend = tdb [printers]

[Shares]
        path = /fileserv
        read only = No
        #guest ok = Yes
        public = Yes
        writable = Yes
        browseable = Yes
        available = Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `[global]` section add:

```
security = share
guest account = nobody
```

in your `[Shares]` section uncomment `guest ok = Yes` and add `browseable = Yes`

Also make sure user `nobody` exists and has read/write/execute privileges to directory `/fileserv`.

Then test your configuration with `testparm`.

Finally once you are happy reload samba: `service samba reload`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want anyone to have to enter a password, do you care about file ownership? That is, if user "Fred" creates a file, is it important for the file to be owned by "Fred"?

If not, there's easy ways to do that. Ditch all the user stuff in your cfg file, try:

security = SHARE

null passwords = Yes

guest account = sambauser (name that I use, account exists, has access to everything)

usershare allow guests = Yes

Then if someone logs in as guest, they have all the priveliges of sambashare.